# Artifactory allows multiple same build-infos..?

Tags: continuous-integration, devops, artifactory

I've noticed that you can publish more then 1 build with the same name & number in Artifactory. Does that make sense? what happens when you promote that build? Do all the artifacts related to both the builds get promoted?

Comment: Here's my answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52229251/2582820

Answer (score 0):

I do this frequently what you will notice is the build number is incremented anyway in the UI. I believe this is a feature to make automation jobs simpler is my guess.